# Cannot run custom Angular 7 elements bundle in Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-elements

Im trying to create a few custom angular 7 elements/components that i can use on a wide range of customer sites. Fx. Wordpress, Angular front ends and so on.

**Setup**

I have bundled my angular elements like this for testing:
package.json command:

```
"build:elements": "ng build --prod=true --outputHashing=none && node build-script.js",
```

build-script.js:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');    

(async function build() {

    const files =[
        './dist/elements/runtime.js',
        './dist/elements/polyfills.js',
        './dist/elements/main.js',
        './dist/elements/scripts.js'
    ]

    await fs.ensureDir('publish')

    await concat(files, 'publish/elements.js')

    console.info('Elements created successfully!')
})()
```

**The problem**

I have created another angular 7 site, where i include the js file in the index file, and i get the following errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQj7D.png)

And i only have a blank page then.. :(

Answer (score 0):

In the src/polyfills.ts file comment that line below and generate build again

//import 'zone.js/dist/zone';